# Can't understand the proof of the Time-Rescaling theorem

Tags: computational-modeling, mathematical-psychology

I was reading the following paper: [The time-rescaling theorem and its application to neural spike train data analysis](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwja6IKqvpLxAhVEzaQKHc9FD5IQFjADegQIAxAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.columbia.edu%2F%7Eliam%2Fteaching%2Fneurostat-spr12%2Fpapers%2Fbrown-et-al%2Ftime-rescaling.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0OLH2P6C8YA4ABNsTGBhix)
and I have some difficulties understanding the *proof* of the *time-rescaling-theorem*.
Here is the first part of the demonstration, my main concern is about the form of the Jacobian of the transformation between $u_k$ and $\tau_k$, so it's not particularly important to understand every bit of information provided below, however, I report part of the paper to add a little bit of context:

---

***Time-Rescaling Theorem.***

*Let $0<u_{1}<u_{2}<, \ldots,<u_{n}<T$ be a realization from a point process with a conditional intensity function $\lambda\left(t \mid H_{t}\right)$ satisfying $0<\lambda\left(t \mid H_{t}\right)$ for all $t \in(0, T] .$ Define the transformation*
$$
\Lambda\left(u_{k}\right)=\int_{0}^{u_{k}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) d u
$$
*for $k=1, \ldots, n$, and assume $\Lambda(t)<\infty$ with probability one for all $t \in(0, T]$. Then the $\Lambda\left(u_{k}\right)$ 's are a Poisson process with unit rate.*

***Proof***.

Let $\tau_{k}=\Lambda\left(u_{k}\right)-\Lambda\left(u_{k-1}\right)$ for $k=1, \ldots, n$ and set $\tau_{T} = \int_{u_n}^{T} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) d u$. To establish the result, it suffices to show that the $\tau_{k}$s are independent and identically distributed exponential random variables with mean one. Because the $\tau_{k}$ transformation is one-to-one and $\tau_{n+1}>\tau_{T}$ if and only if $u_{n+1}>T$, the joint probability density of the $\tau_{k}$ 's is
$$
\begin{array}{l}
f\left(\tau_{1}, \tau_{2}, \ldots, \tau_{n} \cap \tau_{n+1}>\tau_{T}\right)
=f\left(\tau_{1}, \ldots, \tau_{n}\right) \operatorname{Pr}\left(\tau_{n+1}>\tau_{T} \mid \tau_{1}, \ldots, \tau_{n}\right)
\end{array}
$$
The following two events are equivalent
$$
\left\{\tau_{n+1}>\tau_{T} \mid \tau_{1}, \ldots, \tau_{n}\right\}=\left\{u_{n+1}>T \mid u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots, u_{n}\right\}
$$
Hence
$$
\color{black}{
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(\tau_{n+1}>\tau_{T} \mid \tau_{1}, \tau_{2}, \ldots, \tau_{n}\right) &=\operatorname{Pr}\left(u_{n+1}>T \mid u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots, u_{n}\right) \\
&=\exp \left\{-\int_{u_n}^{T} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u_{n}}\right) d u\right\} \\
&=\exp\left\{-\tau_T\right\}
\end{aligned}
}
$$
where the last equality follows from the definition of $\tau_T$.

By the multivariate change-of-variable formula (Port, 1994) we have that
$$
f\left(\tau_{1}, \tau_{2}, \ldots, \tau_{n}\right)=|J| f\left(u_{1}, u_{2}, \ldots, u_{n} \cap N\left(u_{n}\right)=n\right)
$$
where $|J|$ is the determinant of the  Jacobian matrix $J$ of the transformation between $u_{j}, j=1, \ldots, n$ and $\tau_{k}, k=1, \ldots, n$.

---

Now, since we're talking about the transformation from $u_{j}, j=1, \ldots, n$ to $\tau_{k}, k=1, \ldots, n$ I'd expect the Jacobian to look like:

$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \tau_1}{\partial u_1} & \frac{\partial \tau_1}{\partial u_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial \tau_1}{\partial u_n} \\
\frac{\partial \tau_2}{\partial u_1} & \frac{\partial \tau_2}{\partial u_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial \tau_2}{\partial u_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
\frac{\partial \tau_n}{\partial u_1} & \frac{\partial \tau_n}{\partial u_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial \tau_n}{\partial u_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And, given the fact that
$$
\tau_{k}=\Lambda\left(u_{k}\right)-\Lambda\left(u_{k-1}\right) = \int_{0}^{u_{k}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) du - \int_{0}^{u_{k-1}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) du = \int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_{k}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) du
$$

From the first fundamental theorem of calculus we know that $\frac{d}{d x} \int_{a}^{x} f(t) d t=f(x)$, so
$$
\frac{\partial \tau_k}{\partial u_k} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial u_k}\int_{u_{k-1}}^{u_{k}} \lambda\left(u \mid H_{u}\right) du =  \lambda\left(u_k \mid H_{u_k}\right)
$$

Which would translate to

$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \tau_1}{\partial u_1} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \frac{\partial \tau_2}{\partial u_2} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots &\frac{\partial \tau_n}{\partial u_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda\left(u_1 \mid H_{u_1}\right) & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda\left(u_2 \mid H_{u_2}\right) & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots &  \lambda\left(u_n \mid H_{u_n}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

However, the paper continues as:

---

Because $\tau_{k}$ is a function of $\color{black}{u_{1}, \ldots, u_{k}}, J$ is a lower triangular matrix, and its determinant is the product of its diagonal elements defined as $|J|=\left|\prod_{k=1}^{n} J_{k k}\right| .$

By assumption $0<\lambda\left(t \mid H_{t}\right)$ and the definition of $\tau_{k}$, the mapping of $u$ into $\tau$ is one-to-one. Therefore, by the inverse differentiation theorem (Protter & Morrey, 1991), the diagonal elements of $J$ are
$$
J_{k k}=\frac{\partial u_{k}}{\partial \tau_{k}}=\lambda\left(u_{k} \mid H_{u_{k}}\right)^{-1}
$$

---

So apparently the correct Jacobian is

$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \tau_1} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial\tau_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial\tau_n} \\
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial \tau_1} & \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial\tau_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial\tau_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial \tau_1} & \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial\tau_2} & \dots &\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial\tau_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the matrix is lower-triangular.

What am I doing wrong? Which elements of the Jacobian are indeed non-zeros?

Thanks